# Probability/Convolution 2 Questions - Can Someone Help?

Tags: probability, convolution, density-function

I am taking a probability class and I am not fully getting these two problems below. I do know solutions and I don't need the whole calculation but I want to grasp the idea a little bit better.

Suppose again that Z = X + Y. Find $f(z)$.

1. $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ when $0<x<2$; $0$ otherwise.
   I know that $f_Y(y)$ has the same shape as $f_X(x)$.

   **QUESTION 1**: So what is exactly $f_Y(y)$? Is it $\frac{1}{2}$ or ...?
2. $f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-3)$ when $3<x<5$; $0$ otherwise.
   I know that the answer is:
   for $6 <z <8$, we integrate $\frac{1}{4}(x-3)(z-x-3)$ from x=3 to x=z and get $f_Z(z) 
    = \frac{1}{24}(z^3 – 18z^2 + 
      81z – 108)$.
   For $8 <z <10$, we integrate $\frac{1}{4}(x-3)(z-x-3)$ from x=z to x=5 and get $f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{24}(-z^3 + 18z^2 
      – 69z +20)$.

   **QUESTION 2**: Why do we consider only $6<z<8$ and $8<z<10$? What happens between $3<z<6$?
   **QUESTION 3**: Why do we integrate from x=z to to x=5 for $8 <z <10$?

Questions and solutions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIlmp.png)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some context. Apparently $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2)$, but how is $Y$ related to $X$, aside from having the "same shape"? It sounds like it's also uniform, but does $Y$ have the same support as $X$?

Comment: No other context was given, btw.